# Problema con consulta sql para varias condiciones

Tags: sql

tengo esta consulta con la que mediante un formulario cuando selecciono un posgrado y una de las 2 lenguas me trae todos los registros de aquellos alumnos que están inscrito en ese posgrado y esa combinación de lenguas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.nombre, usuarios.email, alumPosgrado.alumnoId, 
alumPosgrado.posgradoId, posgrados.nombrePosgrado
FROM alumPosgrado
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON alumPosgrado.alumnoId = usuarios.id
LEFT JOIN posgrados ON alumPosgrado.posgradoId = posgrados.id
WHERE posgrados.id = {posgrado}
AND (alumPosgrado.lenguaPartidaId = '{$lenguaPartida}' OR alumPosgrado.lenguaMetaId = '{$lenguaMeta}');
```

Sin embargo, me gustaría añadir 2 condiciones más a mi consulta, además de la actual, y no encuentro cómo hacerlo.

La primera sería que cuando seleccione un posgrado me traiga todos los registros que tengan ese posgrado, sin que influya la selección de lenguas.

La otra, que cuando seleccione un posgrado y una lenguaPartida y lenguaMeta me traiga exactamente los registros que tengan esa combinación.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Primero pongo la query y luego la explico:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.nombre, usuarios.email, alumPosgrado.alumnoId, 
alumPosgrado.posgradoId, posgrados.nombrePosgrado
FROM alumPosgrado
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON alumPosgrado.alumnoId = usuarios.id
LEFT JOIN posgrados ON alumPosgrado.posgradoId = posgrados.id
WHERE posgrados.id = {posgrado}
AND (
  (alumPosgrado.lenguaPartidaId = '{$lenguaPartida}' AND alumPosgrado.lenguaMetaId = '{$lenguaMeta}')
  OR
  (alumPosgrado.lenguaPartidaId = '{$lenguaPartida}' AND '{$lenguaMeta}' = '')
  OR
  ('{$lenguaPartida}' = '' AND alumPosgrado.lenguaMetaId = '{$lenguaMeta}')
  OR
  ('{$lenguaPartida}' = '' AND '{$lenguaMeta}' = '')
);
```

La clausula WHERE define:

1. Si el valor de lenguaPartida y lenguaMeta no están vacios, entonces recupera los registros con el posgrado especificado y los valores en lenguaPartida y lenguaMeta que coincidan con los valores ingresados.
2. si el valor de lenguaPartida no es vacío pero el valor de lenguaMeta si, entonces recupera los registros que tengan el posgrado especificado y el valor de lenguaPartida que coincida con el valor ingresado.
3. si el valor de lenguaPartida es vacío pero el valor de lenguaMeta no, entonces recupera los registros con el posgrado especificado y que el valor de lenguaMeta coincida con el valor ingresado.
4. Si ambos lenguaPartida y lenguaMeta son vacíos, entonces recupera los registros que tengan el posgrado especificado sin que influya lenguaPartida y lenguaMeta.